# integration of second order differential equation about SHM

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, physics, indefinite-integrals, chain-rule

This is a differential equation of SHM from my book.
$$\frac{d^2x}{dt^2}=-\omega^2\times x$$
Both sides is multiplied by $\displaystyle 2\frac{dx}{dt}$ for simplification. And now,
$$
2\times \frac{dx}{dt} \frac{d^2x}{dt^2}=-2\omega^2\times x \frac{dx}{dt}$$

Book integrates both sides to simplify it further out of thin air.

I did managed to integrate the RHS but i have no idea how the integration in LHS works. Can someone point it out plz.

I don't know how to integrate it. can someone explain me how I can get LHS: $$\Bigl(\frac{dx}{dt}\Bigr)^2 = -\omega^2 + C$$

It might be stupidly simple but I couldn't find it online somehow.

Comment: Is it sufficient to point out that if you set $v=\dot x$, then the left side is $2v\dot v$, which integrates similar to the right side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding on the comment by @LutzLehmann, the chain rule says that for some function $v$ of $t$,
$$
\frac{d}{dt} \bigl(v^2\bigr) = 2v\frac{dv}{dt},
$$
which becomes
$$
\frac{d}{dt} \biggl(\Bigl(\frac{dx}{dt}\Bigr)^2\biggr) = 2\frac{dx}{dt} \frac{d^2x}{dt^2},
$$
after the substitution $\displaystyle v = \frac{dx}{dt}$.

---

But how do we reverse-engineer the chain rule when faced with an integration problem? In other words, how would we integrate this expression without recognizing the integrand as a derivative a priori? This is essence of *substitution*.

With the substitution $\displaystyle v = \frac{dx}{dt}$, we have
$$
dv = \frac{d}{dt} \biggl(\frac{dx}{dt}\biggr) \, dt 
= \frac{d^2x}{dt^2}\frac{dx}{dt} \, dt 
= \frac{d^2x}{dt^2} \, dx
$$
so
$$
\int 2\,\frac{dx}{dt} \frac{d^2x}{dt^2} \, dx
= \int 2v \, dv 
= v^2 + C 
= \Bigl(\frac{dx}{dt}\Bigr)^2 + C 
$$